# How do I convert my txt file from samba-tool to json file in bash script

Tags: json, linux, type-conversion, txt, samba

at the beginning I would like to write that I am just learning to write scripts. I have a test domain "universum.local" in VBox set on Ubuntu 22.04 ADDC Samba. I would like to query a domain controller for a list of domain users (10) with bash script and save data about them to a json file. At the moment I was able to get the necessary information and save it to a txt file.

Here is my scripts code:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

ldapuserslistfilename="ldapuserslist.txt"
ldapuserslistfile="$tmp/$ldapuserslistfilename"
    
ldapusersinfofilename="ldapusersinfo.txt"
ldapusersinfofile="$tmp/$ldapusersinfofilename"

# main code
touch $ldapuserslistfile
touch $ldapusersinfofile

samba-tool user list > $ldapuserslistfile

while read -r line ; do
 for user in $line ; do
  samba-tool user show $user >> $ldapusersinfofile
 done
done < $ldapuserslistfile

# copying txt files for tests
cp $ldapuserslistfile /mnt
cp $ldapusersinfofile /mnt

# deleting files
if [ -f $ldapuserslistfile ] ; then rm -f $ldapuserslisfile ; fi
if [ -f $ldapusersinfofile ] ; then rm -f $ldapusersinfofile ; fi
```

There is output, all users are saved in the txt file in the form below:

```
dn: CN=Bruce Banner,OU=Users,OU=MARVEL,OU=UNIVERSUM,DC=universum,DC=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: Bruce Banner
sn: Banner
givenName: Bruce
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20220926075536.0Z
whenChanged: 20220926075536.0Z
displayName: Bruce Banner
uSNCreated: 4128
name: Bruce Banner
objectGUID: d1fb86d4-17bc-43f2-af83-ca06fa733e9e
badPwdCount: 0
codePage: 0
countryCode: 0
badPasswordTime: 0
lastLogoff: 0
lastLogon: 0
primaryGroupID: 513
objectSid: S-1-5-21-2846706046-4262971904-2743650290-1109
accountExpires: 9223372036854775807
logonCount: 0
sAMAccountName: hulk
sAMAccountType: 805306368
userPrincipalName: hulk@universum.local
objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=universum,DC=local
pwdLastSet: 0
userAccountControl: 512
uSNChanged: 4132
memberOf: CN=Avengers,OU=Groups,OU=MARVEL,OU=UNIVERSUM,DC=universum,DC=local
distinguishedName: CN=Bruce Banner,OU=Users,OU=MARVEL,OU=UNIVERSUM,DC=universum,DC=local
```

I would like to have this data in json format like

```
{
  "users": [
            {
             "cn" : "Bruce Banner",
             "sn" : "Banner",
             "givenName" : "Bruce",
             "whenCreated" : "20220926075536.0Z",
             "<objectname>" : "<value>",
             "<objectname>" : "<value>",
            },
            {
             <next user info>
            },
            {
             <next user info>
            }
           ]
}
```

objectname is the next user item like lastLogon, lastLogoff, etc. I would like to save all users in the json file so that I can read them with another powershell script on my computer

UPDATE:

I added the lines below

```
# conversion fron txt to json
jsonfilename="jsontestfile.json"
json="./$jsonfilename"
touch $json

ed -s $ldapusersinfofile  << 'EOF' > $json
v/^cn:\|^sn:\|^givenName:\|^displayName:\|^name:\|^whenCreated:/d
,s/^\(.*[^:]*\): \(.*\)/"\1": "\2"/
g/cn\|sn\|givenName\|displayName\|name\|whenCreated/s/$/,/
,s/^/   /
g/lastLogon/t. \
s/.*/},/g
1,$-1g/}/t. \
s/.*/{/g
0a
{
.
$s/,//
,p
Q
EOF
```

between #main code section and # copying txt files for tests section and I have output to json file like

```
{
   "cn": "James Rhodes",
   "sn": "Rhodes",
   "givenName": "James",
   "whenCreated": "20220926075852.0Z",
   "displayName": "James Rhodes",
   "name": "James Rhodes",
   "lastLogon": "0"
},
{
   "cn": "T'Chala",
   "givenName": "T'Chala",
   "whenCreated": "20220926081521.0Z",
   "displayName": "T'Chala",
   "name": "T'Chala",
   "lastLogon": "0"
},
{
   "cn": "Stephen Strange",
   "sn": "Strange",
   "givenName": "Stephen",
   "whenCreated": "20220926080942.0Z",
   "displayName": "Stephen Strange",
   "name": "Stephen Strange",
   "lastLogon": "0"
}
```

to be able to read the jsonfile in my powershells script, there missing

```
    {
        "users": [
```

at the beginig data and

```
      ]
    }
```

at the end of data to have file like

```
{
    "users": [
                   {
                    "cn": "James Rhodes",
                    "sn": "Rhodes",
                    "givenName": "James",
                    "whenCreated": "20220926075852.0Z",
                    "displayName": "James Rhodes",
                    "name": "James Rhodes",
                    "lastLogon": "0"
                   },
                   {
                    "cn": "T'Chala",
                    "givenName": "T'Chala",
                    "whenCreated": "20220926081521.0Z",
                    "displayName": "T'Chala",
                    "name": "T'Chala",
                    "lastLogon": "0"
                   },
                   {
                    "cn": "Stephen Strange",
                    "sn": "Strange",
                    "givenName": "Stephen",
                    "whenCreated": "20220926080942.0Z",
                    "displayName": "Stephen Strange",
                    "name": "Stephen Strange",
                    "lastLogon": "0"
                   }
               ]
}
```

to read by PS script

```
Clear
$json = Get-Content <pathToFile>\jsontestfile.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($user in $json.users){
 echo $user.cn
 echo $user.sn
 echo $user.givenName
 echo "----------"
}
```

how to add missing characters?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Your specification of the input and the expected output is not clear enough. The input seems to show one user only. Which input lines should be written as `"<objectname>" : "<value>",`? Show the script you currently use.

Comment: I update my question and added my code, I hope it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to this:

```
# add prefix
printf '{\n"users" :\n[\n' > $json
# add converted users data
ed -s $data << 'EOF' >> $json
v/^cn:\|^sn:\|^givenName:\|^whenCreated:\|^displayName:\|^name:\|^badPwdCount:\|^badPasswordTime:\|^lastLogoff:\|^primaryGroupID:\|^accountExpires:\|^sAMAccountName:\|^userPrincipalName:\|^pwdLastSet:\|^userAccountControl:\|^lastLogonTimestamp:\|^whenChanged:\|^lastLogon:\|^logonCount:\|^distinguishedName:/d
,s/^\(.*[^:]*\): \(.*\)/"\1" : "\2"/
g/cn\|sn\|givenName\|whenCreated\|displayName\|name\|badPwdCount\|badPasswordTime\|lastLogoff\|primaryGroupID\|accountExpires\|sAMAccountName\|userPrincipalName\|pwdLastSet\|userAccountControl\|lastLogonTimestamp\|whenChanged\|lastLogon\|logonCount/s/$/,/
,s/^/  /
g/distinguishedName/t. \
s/.*/},/g
1,$-1g/}/t. \
s/.*/{/g
0a
{
.
$s/,//
,p
Q
EOF
# add suffix
printf ']\n}' >> $json
```

It now works and Powershell can read my file.

Answer (score 0):

You need 'jq' and then parse the output of samba-tool, like this:

```bash
sudo samba-tool user show $USERNAME -H ldap://<DC_SHORT_HOSTNAME> -d0 | jq -R -s -c 'split("\n")'
```

You can easily use a 'for loop' around a list of usernames.